# iOS Auto rotation of view at first

Tags: ios, rotation, landscape-portrait

I am working on an ios app that must work in both landscape and portrait, except one view, that should be always in landscape. So, I have:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

If I lunch my application in landscape mode, and get to this view and rotate the device (iPad), this method is called and return false, so the interface doesn't rotate, good stuff.

BUT if I am in portrait and get to this view, this method is called and return a false, however the orientation doesn't change. In this context, if I rotate the device to landscape, the method return a true and the interface rotate properly and if I tried to rotate again to portrait, this method return false and the interface remains in landscape.

How can I achieve that the first time I get to this view, if the device is in portrait, the interface change to landscape?

Also, I tried with

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

but it never get called.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is depreciated in iOS 6.0. Override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods instead.

From the docs on `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

> If your view controller implements this method, then when presented,
>   its view is shown in the preferred orientation (although it can later
>   be rotated to another supported rotation). If you do not implement
>   this method, the system presents the view controller using the current
>   orientation of the status bar.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't explain myself well. I am running my app in an iOS 5 device, and every time I show the view I want only show in landscape, the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is called, but if I am in portrait, despite it return NO, the view is showed in portrait. If I rotate to landscape then it return YES and the view is rotated and if I rotate again to portrait, it return NO and the view remain in landscape as it should. My problem is that the first time, when the method return NO I need the view to rotate to portrait instead of remain in portrait.